# window scroll on load issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a transparent `navbar` with the following markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
```

the `navbar` looks like this on my landing page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Cj3.png)

when I scroll down and reach the `#content` div which is the white block:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEiOB.png)

I remove `navbar-dark` class and add `.bg-light` to add a gray/white background to the `navbar`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEjIl.png)

As you can see, it works well and does what it's supposed to do.

The problem is when I reload the screen and I'm not on top of the window, for example, below the `#content` div.

First, then the `.navbar` won't appear because it still has the `navbar-dark` class so until I scroll at least 1 pixel it won't change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCVFa.png)

That is not a big problem, but the biggest one is that, if I scroll up, even though I pass the `#content` div, the `.navbar` won't remove the `bg-light` (white-background) class so it looks like this always:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgvp5.png)

This ONLY happens if I load the page after the page is scrolled, not if I load the page without having scrolled it before.

This is my code, hope you can help me and tell me what's the problem here:

```
let contentTop = mainContent.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  if (window.scrollY >= contentTop.top + document.body.scrollTop) {
    navbarFixed.classList.add("bg-light");
    navbarFixed.classList.remove("navbar-dark");
  } else {
    navbarFixed.classList.remove("bg-light");
    navbarFixed.classList.add("navbar-dark");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind : Why don't you make a function that will check how far are you from top of the page when the page loads ?

By doing this, you will always have the appropriate class, and scrolling will do it's job as it should.

Comment: I thought i'm already doing that with `if (window.scrollY >= contentTop.top + document.body.scrollTop) `

Comment: Yes, but you are doing that on scroll. :) You also gotta check when the page loads, when no scrolling has been done yet.